# Draw Polyline from Marker on click Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polyline

This is a follow-up to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751118/google-maps-api-push-marker-lat-lng-on-click-to-array-for-line-path) I made a few days ago, in attempt to go at my challenge in a new direction. My goal is when I click on a marker, I would like the origin lat/lng of my polyline to be the same lat/lng as that marker. The trick that I am running into is where to put the line creation in my for loop of my markers where the on click exists so that the line will use the coordinates of the marker, verse the declared. Since I declare my lat/lng variables outside of this function, the line defaults to their values: `var oLat = 10.1 var oLng = 22.1`rather than the values inside my for loop. Here is my current for loop:

```
for (var i in points) {
var p = points[i];
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[1], p[2]);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: points[i][3],
    zIndex: p[5],
    title: p[0]     
});

overviewMarkers.push(marker);


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(points[i][6] + '<div id="infopanel">'+
  '<input onclick="addLine();" type=button value="Show Routes">'+
  '<input onclick="removeLine();" type=button value="Remove Routes"></div>');
      infowindow.open(map, marker)
     oLat = parseFloat(this.position.lat().toFixed(4))
     oLng = parseFloat(this.position.lng().toFixed(4))
        }      
    })(marker, i) );        
}//end for loop
```

I have attempted placing my line code (below) after the `oLng = parseFloat(this.position.lng().toFixed(4))` but then my line wont draw. If I keep my line code outside of the entire function, it will draw with the default values. Line creation code (I added an alert just to confirm that my var would capture the on-click value):

```
var arrayLine=[]
var originPoint = [new google.maps.LatLng(oLat,oLng)];
var destPoint = [new google.maps.LatLng(51.9279723,4.4904063),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.136482, -73.831299),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(34.0204989,-118.4117325)                 
                ];
var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW                  
};

for (var d in destPoint) {
    var t = destPoint[d];

  var linePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [originPoint[0],[t][0]], 
    strokeColor: '#4A484D',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    geodesic: true,
      icons: [{
    icon: lineSymbol,
    offset: '100%',
    repeat: '60px'
  }]

  });
   arrayLine.push(linePath)

function setLines(map) {
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLine.length; i++) {
    arrayLine[i].setMap(map);
    }
   }
  }
function addLine() {
setLines(map);
alert(parseFloat(oLat));
}
```

I have attempted to look at the [complex polyine example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex?csw=1) that google provides, but it seems a little more simplified then what I am attempting to do.

Comment: fix your javascript errors [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5fajLgn/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to create the polyline in the marker click listener (where the marker is accessible and you can get its position).
2. use documented methods (.getPosition(), not undocumented properties .position)

```
for (var i in points) {
    var p = points[i];
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[1], p[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: points[i][3],
        zIndex: p[5],
        map: map,
        title: p[0]
    });

    overviewMarkers.push(marker);


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            var originPoint = this.getPosition();
            var oLat = parseFloat(this.getPosition().lat().toFixed(4));
            var oLng = parseFloat(this.getPosition().lng().toFixed(4));
            for (var d in destPoint) {
                var t = destPoint[d];

                var linePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: [originPoint, [t][0]],
                    strokeColor: '#4A484D',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    geodesic: true,
                    icons: [{
                        icon: lineSymbol,
                        offset: '100%',
                        repeat: '60px'
                    }],
                    map: map

                });
                arrayLine.push(linePath);
            }
            infowindow.setContent(points[i][6] + '<div id="infopanel">' +
                '<input onclick="addLine();" type=button value="Show Routes">' +
                '<input onclick="removeLine();" type=button value="Remove Routes"></div>');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, i));
} //end for loop
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x5fajLgn/11/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var arrayLine = [];
var overviewMarkers = [];
var oLat, oLng;

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 180);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: myLatlng
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  var points = [
    ['Karachi, Pakistan', 25.0111453, 67.0647043, 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png', 'Overview', 1, '<h4>Sample Text</h4'],
    ['Bangkok, Thailand', 13.7246005, 100.6331108, 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png',
      'Overview', 1, '<h4>Sample Text</h4>'
    ],
    ['Rotterdam, Netherlands', 51.9279723, 4.4904063, 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png', 'Overview', 1, '<h4>Sample Text</h4>'],
    ['New York, NY, USA', 40.7056308, -73.9780035, 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png', 'Overview', 1, '<h4>Sample Text</h4>'],
    ['Memphis, TN, USA', 35.129186, -89.9696395, 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png', 'Overview', 1, '<h4>Sample Text</h4>']
  ];

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var originPoint = [];
  // Creates markers  
  for (var i in points) {
    var p = points[i];
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[1], p[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      icon: points[i][3],
      zIndex: p[5],
      map: map,
      title: p[0]
    });

    overviewMarkers.push(marker);


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        var originPoint = this.getPosition();
        var oLat = parseFloat(this.getPosition().lat().toFixed(4));
        var oLng = parseFloat(this.getPosition().lng().toFixed(4));
        for (var d in destPoint) {
          var t = destPoint[d];

          var linePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [originPoint, [t][0]],
            strokeColor: '#4A484D',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            geodesic: true,
            icons: [{
              icon: lineSymbol,
              offset: '100%',
              repeat: '60px'
            }],
            map: map

          });
          arrayLine.push(linePath);
        }
        infowindow.setContent(points[i][6] + '<div id="infopanel">' +
          '<input onclick="addLine();" type=button value="Show Routes">' +
          '<input onclick="removeLine();" type=button value="Remove Routes"></div>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, i));
  } //end for loop  
}
var arrayLine = [];
var originPoint = [new google.maps.LatLng(oLat, oLng)];
var destPoint = [new google.maps.LatLng(51.9279723, 4.4904063),
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.136482, -73.831299),
  new google.maps.LatLng(34.0204989, -118.4117325)
];
var lineSymbol = {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW
};

function addLine() {
  setLines(map);
  // alert(parseFloat(oLat));
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function setLines(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLine.length; i++) {
    arrayLine[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function removeLine() {
  setLines(null);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
#infopanel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <input onclick="showFactoryMarkers();" type=button value="Show Factories">
  <input onclick="showCFSMarkers();" type=button value="Show CFS">
  <input onclick="showPortMarkers();" type=button value="Show Ports">
  <input onclick="hideMarkers();" type=button value="Hide All">
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response and cleaned up code, this makes much more sense. The one part that I don't understand is if I want the polyline to be displayed via a function, verses setting the map property to map in the line creation, where would that function be placed? The idea is that `function setLines(map)` would be initiated from two other functions, either setting setLines(map) or setLines(Null). This way the line can be shown/hidden via html. Again, thanks for your help, still very new to this. Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5fajLgn/5/)

Comment: If you want that to work, fix the javascript errors (`Uncaught ReferenceError: setLines is not defined`)

Comment: Perfect, so moving the setLines function outside of the initialize function, allows it to be called. Final question, how did you test the code to get the above error, that would be very helpful to figure stuff on my own in the future!

Comment: To call functions from HTML click listeners, they either need to be in the global scope, or you need to use google.maps.event.addDomListener from somewhere where they are in scope.  For error messages, look in the browser javascript console, I typically use Chrome, unless it is a browser specific issue.  [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Troubleshooting)