# Show Polyline after marker click event when dealing with multiple markers.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I am working on a web application that uses Google Maps API v3. I am creating ~ 400 markers in an hour, which are being pushed in currentlyDisplayedMarkers[]. For each marker, I am creating a Polyline containing its past locations. This works ok. However, I want to show the Polyline for a marker only when that specific marker is clicked. I created a function, called addClickHandler in which I define the onClick listener for each marker. When the marker is clicked, the Polyline should be added to the map.

When I click the marker the Polyline is not shown on the map. 
Do you have any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

```
    if (!found)
                   {
                       var LatLng = { lat: data[i].Plots[0].Latitude, lng: data[i].Plots[0].Longitude };
                       createMarker(LatLng, 90, data[i].TrackNumber);
                       drawPolyline(data[i].Plots);
                   }
function createMarker(markerLatLng, direction, id) {
var iconImage = {
    path: 'M265.54,0H13.259C5.939,0,0.003,5.936,0.003,13.256v252.287c0,7.32,5.936,13.256,13.256,13.256H265.54c7.318,0,13.256-5.936,13.256-13.256V13.255C278.796,5.935,272.86,0,265.54,0z M252.284,252.287H26.515V26.511h225.769V252.287z',
    strokeColor: '#800000',
    scale: 0.05,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1
}
//draw the marker and attach it to the map
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: iconImage,
    draggable: false
});
//add aditional properties to the marker
marker.metadata = {
    id: id
};

//add the marker to the markers array
currentlyDisplayedMarkers.push(marker);
for (var j = 0; j < currentlyDisplayedMarkers.length; j++) {
    var pathMarker = currentlyDisplayedMarkers[j];
    addClickHandler(pathMarker);
}
}
function addClickHandler(pathMarker) {
google.maps.event.addListener(pathMarker, 'click', function () {
    flightPath.setMap(map);
});
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It would be too much if I would show more of the code. The code is tested and in my opinion readable enough if you are interested in the matter. Should I provide a complete code, I would have to post also the data source, which I am afraid it is impossible.

Comment: Provide test data that exercises the code, doesn't have to be the "real" data.

Comment: I think that anyone with enough experience would "see" the problem easily. I am quite sure that any type of debug would be useless here, so I do not see the point of providing more information. In my opinion, the help for my issue can only come from someone who has seen this situation before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw Polyline from Marker on click Google Maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794321/draw-polyline-from-marker-on-click-google-maps-api-v3) - [fiddle from that question, modified to work](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x5fajLgn/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You should move the block below to outside of your `createMarker()` function.

```
for (var j = 0; j < currentlyDisplayedMarkers.length; j++) {
    var pathMarker = currentlyDisplayedMarkers[j];
    addClickHandler(pathMarker);
}
```

There is not need to iterate through currently DisplayedMakers collection for just adding eventhandler to each marker everytime you create one.

Just add an eventhandler to that mark which you just created is enough.

Solution: 
Either move the iteration to outside of you marker creation function or just add one event handler for the marker you just created in marker creation function.

Comment: Thank you! It was, indeed, a useless practice to have the loop there. However, I still do not seem to see any change.

Comment: I assume your entire code is inside another iteration indexed as `i`, and I see in each loop, you create a polyline object after the marker is created. I assume in your `drawPolyline` function you have assigned currentlyDisplayedMarkers to the flightPath polyline. When you don't have any "click" event, the logic is synchronous, so flightPath is drawn and set to map right after each marker is created. But Once you added a 'click' event, the logic is asynchronous. previous flightPath will be replaced with the last object in your dataset. there will be no changes at all when you click the marker.

Comment: What you need to do is to create another collection called `var flightPaths = []`, and in your drawPolyline function you push each path with its `id` to this new collection', then write a sub-function and call it to get the flightPath from that collection by `id` from the Marker.metadata. Finally setMap.